# *ngFor breaks css overflow

Tags: html, css, angular

I made a list to test the overflow of a div. The problem is, the overflow dont works correct:

[image: overflow]

Instead of using the overflow scroll, it goes invisible through the div?

This is my html:

```html
<div class="modelSamples">
  <div id="samplesTitle">
    SAMPLES
  </div>
  <div class="sampleList">
    <div id="samples" *ngFor="let tape of sampeList">
      <div id="sampleName"> {{tape.name}} </div>
        <div id="samplePlay">
          <mat-icon> play_circle </mat-icon>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```html
.modelSamples{
    overflow-y: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 60%;
    background-color: rgb(191 126 235 / 29%);
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
#samplesTitle{
    display: flex;
    font-family: Oswald;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 2rem;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
#samples{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    font-family: Oswald;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
#sampleName, #samplePlay{
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
#samplePlay{
    padding-right: 30px;
}
```

I also tried it with using max-height for .sampleList but that also dont work

Comment: Without ngFor the behavior is exactly the same. What is the problem?

Comment: .modalSamples has a height of 60%. I would say this functions as designed.

Comment: You need to be using class selectors instead of ids. DOM id properties should be unique for each element.